# Howto pass array values via from ejs to Javascript?

Tags: javascript, node.js, ejs

I am passing an array via ejs with JavaScript. I can get to the values inside ejs but not from JavaScript. Below is more information.

node.js

```
FileTypes = {"application/octet-stream":20,
                 "audio/mpeg":12,
                 "text/html" :71}
res.render('index.ejs', {FileTypes: JSON.stringify(FileTypes)});
```

index.ejs

```
 <script type="text/javascript">

   var FileTypes =  <%=FileTypes%>;
   //Error message on the console - Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token & 

 </script>
```

Any ideas?

Comment: What is populating  <%=FileTypes%>? A templating system? A delimited value like this is not part of standard JavaScript.

Comment: What does the rendered file look like?

Comment: @Diodeus OP said in the title, body, and tags: EJS. https://github.com/visionmedia/ejs

Comment: If that's the case, this injection method is designed to work with HTML, not with injecting code into SCRIPT blocks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using the `<%= %>` tag in EJS will escape the output, so `{"application/octet-stream": ... }` is being turned into `{&quot;application/octet-stream&quot;: ... }`, resulting in JavaScript like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">                                                                                                                                          
  var FileTypes = {&quot;application/octet-stream&quot;:20,&quot;audio/mpeg&quot;:12,&quot;text/html&quot;:71};
</script>
```

So, you can see where the "Unexpected token &" is coming from. The solution is to use the `<%- %>` tag, which won't escape the output:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  var FileTypes = <%- FileTypes %>;
  //      here -----^
</script>
```

...and will give you what you want:

```
<script type="text/javascript">                                                                                                                                          
  var FileTypes = {"application/octet-stream":20,"audio/mpeg":12,"text/html":71};
</script>
```

Comment: Yup, that's what I assumed. The value of FileType should be available directly though without templating it. EXT is JS and that is just a variable.